# Help please, i have 2 red wires

Tags: light-fixture

[image: 3][image][image: wiring]Im trying to connect an outside motion sensor light to a light switch but not sure which one is live, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Test using a meter.

Comment: Need more information.  What wires are at the switch and the wires from the light.  Pictures will help.

Comment: Pics added, thanks

Comment: Sorry but ive no idea how to test with a meter even if i did have one

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the light the existing switch controls?

Comment: What country? Two reds would be uncommon in the US. One of the wires appears to have a tape tag on it, but I don't know non-US conventions for whether that indicates hot or return.  Unfortunately the right answer *IS* to test with a meter, or possibly a non-contact AC tracer (with the switch turned off either way, of course). If you don't know how, you probably want to get help from someone who does.

Comment: Hi, appreciate the comments, thanks for taking the time to chip in here. Im for the UK, this house has the old wiring, old wiring, Red and Black, which now i believe is is old red is = Brown (live), old black = Blue (neutral)

Comment: Its a single gang light switch for the two lights in the garage, i did upload 3 pics at the top there